# Condense Java Code

Tags: java

I've finished creating a hangman game and I'm looking to condense the code since huge chunks of it are repeated with slight differences.

Is there an easy way for me to condense my code?

```
// 'Info' label set text to 'Info' string
InfoLabel.setText(InfoS);
// 'Image' label set enabled to 'false'
ImageLabel.setEnabled(false);
// 'Char' text field set enabled to 'false'
CharTextField.setEnabled(false);
// 'Char' text field set focusable to 'false'
CharTextField.setFocusable(false);
// 'Play' button set enabled to 'false'
PlayButton.setEnabled(false);
// 'Play' button set focusable to 'false'
PlayButton.setFocusable(false);
// Char# labels set enabled to 'false'
Char0Label.setEnabled(false);
Char1Label.setEnabled(false);
Char2Label.setEnabled(false);
Char3Label.setEnabled(false);
Char4Label.setEnabled(false);
Char5Label.setEnabled(false);
Char6Label.setEnabled(false);
Char7Label.setEnabled(false);
Char8Label.setEnabled(false);
Char9Label.setEnabled(false);
// Alphabet labels set enabled to 'false'
ALabel.setEnabled(false);
BLabel.setEnabled(false);
CLabel.setEnabled(false);
DLabel.setEnabled(false);
ELabel.setEnabled(false);
FLabel.setEnabled(false);
GLabel.setEnabled(false);
HLabel.setEnabled(false);
ILabel.setEnabled(false);
JLabel.setEnabled(false);
KLabel.setEnabled(false);
LLabel.setEnabled(false);
MLabel.setEnabled(false);
NLabel.setEnabled(false);
OLabel.setEnabled(false);
PLabel.setEnabled(false);
QLabel.setEnabled(false);
RLabel.setEnabled(false);
SLabel.setEnabled(false);
TLabel.setEnabled(false);
ULabel.setEnabled(false);
VLabel.setEnabled(false);
WLabel.setEnabled(false);
XLabel.setEnabled(false);
YLabel.setEnabled(false);
ZLabel.setEnabled(false);
// 'PlayAgain' button set visible to 'true'
PlayAgainButton.setVisible(true);
```

Above is the displayed java code snippet.

Comment: Not unless you can show us your code. http://pastie.org

Comment: You may use agar-agar which is a gelatinous substance derived from a polysaccharide which is a natural thickener :D

Comment: @paranoid-android Sorry, thought I put the code in before.

Comment: Also, Java naming conventions suggest that you start *variable* names with **lowercase**, and *class* names with **uppercase**. For example, `JLabel someLabel = new JLabel();`

Comment: @paranoid-android Would this adversely affect my code? But thank you for the tip, I'll ensure to use this convention next time.

Comment: As mentioned from the user below  "I think I understand what you're saying, although I've not used 'for' before", that means that this is either a troll or the laziest new learner ever

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you should extract methods from you code using method parameters for the slight differences.

From your code, if you had a list of all your labels you could do something like

```
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
// ... add a your labels to this list when creating them

for (JLabel label : labels) {
    label.setEnabled(false);
    // do other initialisations
}
```

Comment: Okay, so working with the above code how would I implement this, I think I understand what you're saying, although I've not used 'for' before.

Comment: Well, **if you hadn't use `for` before**... you must study more. Let this program as is and move on. Learn and practice (small practices). Then you'll be more confident and you'll can *refactor* your code. *Refactoring: changing internal structure of the code without changing its external behaviour.*

Comment: @helios Thank you, I've finished my code now I'm preparing to submit it, although at it's current state is around 21 pages long.

Comment: By the way, to use the @Bedwyr's sample you must create a labelList containing all references. There are several ways to do it. It's just a way: `Label[] labelList = new Label[] {ALabel, BLabel, CLabel, /* put other labels here */ };`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say from such a general question, but you should look for the points of similarity, and work out where those "slight differences" are:

- Are they *repeated* slight differences? (i.e. you use the same slightly-different value in multiple places.) Could they be encapsulated as state in a new type?
- Could you specify those differences as *parameters* to a new method which is called instead of the existing near-duplicate code?

Basically look for ways of extracting the near-duplicate code into methods - focus initially on identifying both the commonality and the points of difference, and the way forward should become clearer.

EDIT: In the case you've given, it sounds like you've got lots of individual variables which all need to be treated in a similar way. Consider creating a *collection* of values, rather than lots of individual variables.

Comment: Sorry, thought I put the code in before. I'm fairly new to Java development and I've not learnt about the things you have mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays** and **Methods**

For example:

```
JLabel [] alphabet = new JLabel[26];
int c = 'a';
for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
    alphabet[i] = new JLabel(a++ + "");
    alphabet[i].setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: What does this do exactly? Also each of the labels is differently named.

Comment: You don't need to create so many separate ones. Just access them by array index instead. It just loops through them all.

Comment: I've not used an array index before, could you explain them to me or link me to a source?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use reflection.

```
public void enableOnly(JLabel label) {
    try {
        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (JLabel.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
                JLabel label2 = (JLabel) f.get(this);
                label.setEnabled(label == label2);
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

This has the nice feature that you can add labels to your class without having to maintain a list of them.